# How to read data into an array

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have FORTRAN 77 code from an engineering textbook that I would like to make use of. The problem is that I am unable to understand how I input the data into the arrays that are called namely: `FDAM1(61),FDAM2(61),FPOW1(61),FPOW2(61),UDAM(61)` and `UPOW(61).`

For your reference the code has been taken from Page 49 of this book: https://books.google.pt/books?id=i2hyniQpecYC&lpg=PR6&dq=optimal%20design%20siddall&pg=PA49#v=onepage&q=optimal%20design%20siddall&f=false

```
C     PROGRAM TST (INPUT,OUTPUT,TAPE5=INPUT,TAPE6=OUTPUT)
C
C     PROGRAM TO ESTIMATE MAXIMUM EXPECTED VALUE FOR ALTERNATE DESIGNS
C
C     FDENS(I)= ARRAYS FOR DATA DEFINING DENSITY FUNCTIONS
C     FDAM1(I)= ARRAY DEFINING DENSITY FUNCTION FOR DAMAGE IN DESIGN 1
C     DFAM2(I)= ARRAY DEFINING DENSITY FUNCTION FOR DAMAGE IN DESIGN 2
C     FPOW1(I)= ARRAY DEFINING DENSITY FUNCTION FOR POWER IN DESIGN 1
C     FPOW2(I)= ARRAY DEFINING DENSITY FUNCTION FOR POWER IN DESIGN 2
C     UDAM(I)= VALUE CURVE FOR DAMAGE
C     UPOW(I)= VALUE CURVE FOR POWER
C
      DIMENSION FDENS(61),FDAM1(61),FDAM2(61),FPOW1(61),FPOW2(61),
     1UDAM(61),UPOW(61),FUNC(61)
C
C     NORMALIZE DENSITY FUNCTIONS
C
      DO 1 I=1,4
      READ(5,10)(FDENS(J),J=1,61)
      READ(5,11)RANGE
      AREA=FSIMP(FDENS,RANGE,61)
      DO 2 J=1,61
      GO TO(3,4,5,6)I
3     FDAM1(J)=FDENS(J)/AREA
      GO TO 2
4     FDAM2(J)=FDENS(J)/AREA
      GO TO 2
5     FPOW1(J)=FDENS(J)/AREA
      GO TO 2
6     FPOW2(J)=FDENS(J)/AREA
2     CONTINUE
1     CONTINUE
C
C     DETERMINE EXPECTED VALUES
C
      READ(5,10)(UDAM(J),J=1,61)
      READ(5,10)(UPOW(J),J=1,61)
      DO 20 I=1,6
      GO TO (30,31,32,33,34,35)I
30    DO 40 J=1,61
40    FUNC(J)=FDAM1(J)*UDAM(J)
      RANGE=12.
      E1=FSIMP(FUNC,RANGE,61)
      GO TO 20
31    DO 41 J=1,61
41    FUNC(J)=FDAM2(J)*UDAM(J)
C
      RANGE=12.
      E2=FSIMP(FUNC,RANGE,61)
      GO TO 20
32    DO 42 J=1,61
      RANGE=60.
42    FUNC(J)=FPOW1(J)*UPOW(J)
      E3=FSIMP(FUNC,RANGE,61)
33    DO 43 J=1,61
43    FUNC(J)=FPOW2(J)*UPOW(J)
      RANGE=60.
      E4=FSIMP(FUNC,RANGE,61)
      GO TO 20
34    E5=8.17
      GO TO 20
35    E6=2.20
20    CONTINUE
      DES1=E1+E3+E5
      DES2=E2+E4+E6
C
C     OUTPUT
C
      WRITE(6,100)
100   FORMAT(/,1H ,15X,24HEXPECTED VALUES OF VALUE,//)
      WRITE(6,101)
101   FORMAT(/,1H ,12X,6HDAMAGE,7X,5HPOWER,9X,5HPARTS,8X,5HTOTAL,//)
      WRITE(6,102)E1,E3,E5,DES1
102   FORMAT(/,1H ,8HDESIGN 1,4X,F5.3,8X,F5.3,9X,F5.3,8X,F6.3)
      WRITE(6,103)E2,E4,E6,DES2
103   FORMAT(/,1H ,8HDESIGN 2,4X,F5.3,8X,F5.3,9X,F5.3,8X,F6.3)
10    FORMAT(16F5.2)
11    FORMAT(F5.0)
      STOP
      END
```

---

```
SUBROUTINE FSIMP

      FUNCTION FSIMP(FUNC,RANGE,MINT)
C.... CALCULATES INTEGRAL BY SIMPSONS RULE WITH
C     MODIFICATION IF MINT IS EVEN
C.... INPUT
C        FUNC = ARRAY OF EQUALLY SPACED VALUES OF FUNCTION
C               DIMENSION MINT
C        RANGE = RANGE OF INTEGRATION
C        MINT = NUMBER OF STATIONS
C.... OUTPUT
C        FSIMP = AREA
      DIMENSION FUNC(1)
C.... CHECK MINT FOR ODD OR EVEN
      XX=RANGE/(3.*FLOAT(MINT-1))
      M=MINT/2*2
      IF(M.EQ.MINT) GO TO 3
C.... ODD
      AREA=FUNC(1)+FUNC(M)
      MM=MINT-1
      DO 1 I=2,MM,2
1     AREA=AREA+4.*FUNC(I)
      MM=MM-1
      DO 2 I=3,MM,2
2     AREA=AREA+2.*FUNC(I)
      FSIMP=XX*AREA
      RETURN
C.... EVEN
C.... USE SIMPSONS RULE FOR ALL BUT THE LAST 3 INTERVALS
3     M=MINT-3
      AREA=FUNC(1)+FUNC(M)
      MM=M-1
      DO 4 I=2,MM,2
4     AREA=AREA+4.*FUNC(I)
      MM=MM-1
      DO 5 I=3,MM,2
5     AREA=AREA+2.*FUNC(I)
      FSIMP=XX*AREA
C.... USE NEWTONS 3/3 RULE FOR LAST THREE INTERVALS
      FSIMP=FSIMP+9./3.*XX*(FUNC(MINT-3)+3.*(FUNC(MINT-2)+FUNC(MINT-1))
      1 +FUNC(MINT))
      RETURN
      END
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow. Try to keep your posts concise. Avoid greetings and thanks. Your name is under the post with your icon. The title should introduce the problem, not the broad topic, that is indicated by the tags. Don't just repeat the tags in the title. Use rather generic and broader tags like [tag:fortran], add a tag for a specific version only if necessary to distinguish or indicate that you don't want any solution which uses a more recent version.

Comment: Some of the arrays you ask about are calculated automatically inside the program. The other's are read bu the `read` statement. Do you have a description of the input data format? If yes edit the question to include it.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for your response. The original code listing with data can be found in the link shown in the original question. The author has just added it under the main code which is why I am confused...

Comment: Unfortunately page 49 in the link cannot be viewed as the maximum number of views has been exceeded. The data is on page 50. It would be good to make an exact copy and put it in the question. I hope it might be fair use. What is your problem? To understand which number is which? Or something else?

Comment: I was able to screen grab the data and added to the question. I have a feeling the right-most numbers may have been chopped off by whoever originally scanned the book.

Comment: After a better look I'm quite certain that data is supposed to be 80 columns wide (16 5 digit fields per line).  Looks like it was clipped to 72 (imagine that).

Comment: @agentp The data is in relation to picking the best design option. As it is a worked example I would be happy to fudge the numbers to get the program to run. It is useful to know that the numbers have been clipped... that does make a bit more sense now! I will try and upload the code of FSIMP for reference as well. My apologies for not uploading the source code as an image... this is my first time here. Many thanks for finding it and doing it on my behalf.

Comment: To recap my thinking was that I would be able to insert data into the arrays by 'DATA FDAM1/1.0,2.0,3.0...etc/ however if I try this the program just hangs. This is why I was thinking that a differet approach was required to get the program to read correctly.

Comment: @Andy No, never upload source code as an image. All source codes, datafiles, error messages should be included as properly formatted text! Here the image is only to show what kind of information is availble.

Comment: Note also that in older versions of FORTRAN, blanks could sometimes be interpreted as zeroes (unsure if this is vendor- or version-specific) so beware that some of those input lines are filled with spaces which are interpreted as floating point values. Format line 10 is key; the code expects 80 columns of numerical data split into sixteen 5 character chunks, each representing a (small) real number. This is by no means obvious until you've stared too deeply into the abyss that is ancient FORTRAN...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example to help you get started:

```
C Minimal working example of creaky old FORTRAN I/O
      PROGRAM ABYSS
      IMPLICIT NONE
C
      REAL FDENS(61)
      REAL XRANGE
      INTEGER J
C
10    FORMAT(16F5.2)
11    FORMAT(F5.0)

909   FORMAT(/, 'BEHOLD! A DENSITY DISTRIBUTION',/)
910   FORMAT(10(F5.2, 3X),/)
911   FORMAT(/, 'XRANGE is ', F6.1)
C
      CONTINUE
C
      READ(5,10) (FDENS(J), J=1,61)
      READ(5,11) XRANGE
C
      WRITE(6,909)
      WRITE(6,910) (FDENS(J), J=1,61) 
      WRITE(6,911) XRANGE
C
      STOP
      END
```

Apologies for writing this in F77; I'm sticking with the style of the code posted above for the sake of this example. Ideally, you'd use a F03 or F08 for new code or a completely different language which actually has decent I/O features and a rich standard library. But I digress.

This code will operate on the data (be careful to preserve the spaces):

```
                               0.1  0.3  0.5  0.9  1.30 1.90 2.50 3.20 3.80 4.20
 4.70 5.0  5.1  5.2  5.2  5.1  4.9  4.7  4.6  4.4  4.2  3.9  3.8  3.6  3.4  3.2 
 3.0  2.9  2.7  2.5  2.4  2.2  2.1  1.9  1.8  1.6  1.5  1.4  1.2  1.1  1.0  0.9 
 0.8  0.7  0.6  0.5  0.4  0.3  0.3  0.2  0.1  0.1                
 12.
```

to produce

```
BEHOLD! A DENSITY DISTRIBUTION

 0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.10    0.30    0.50    0.90

 1.30    1.90    2.50    3.20    3.80    4.20    4.70    5.00    5.10    5.20

 5.20    5.10    4.90    4.70    4.60    4.40    4.20    3.90    3.80    3.60

 3.40    3.20    3.00    2.90    2.70    2.50    2.40    2.20    2.10    1.90

 1.80    1.60    1.50    1.40    1.20    1.10    1.00    0.90    0.80    0.70

 0.60    0.50    0.40    0.30    0.30    0.20    0.10    0.10    0.00    0.00

 0.00

XRANGE is   12.0
```

If the code is in `abyss.f`, the input data is in `abyss.dat`, you should be able to build the code with

```
gfortran -g -Wall -Og -o abyss abyss.f
```

and generate similar results by running

```
abyss < abyss.dat > abyss.out
```

A key point to note is that the original code is reading from unit 5 (traditionally taken as `stdin`, now officially canonized in `iso_fortran_env` as `INPUT_UNIT`). In your own code, I'd suggest reading from a data file, so replace the literal `5` with whatever variable contains the unit number of the file you're reading from (hint: consider using the `newunit` argument to the `open` command introduced in Fortran 2008. It solves the perennially stupid Fortran problem of trying to find a free I/O unit number.) While you can use I/O redirection, it's suboptimal; it's used here to show how to work around the limitations of the original code.

Also, for the sake of later generations and your own sanity, please avoid taking advantage of Cold-War-era FORTRAN misfeatures such as this spaces-equal-zeroes nonsense. If your data is worth using, it's worth putting in a sensible format which can be easily parsed; columnar, space-delimited values are as good a choice as any. Fortran may actually get a standard library which can read and write CSV files sometime around 2156 (give or take a century) so you have plenty of time to design something decent...

Comment: *Apologies for writing this in F77*  but you just couldn't resist that `IMPLICIT NONE` could you !

Comment: Look, just because I wrote it in F77 doesn't mean I have to write it in /bad/ F77 ;)